# Can't make HTACCESS rewrite with pameters

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a routing system set up in my system already. But I am trying to add one exception to it, so at the beginning of my HTACCESS I added

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} anything
RewriteRule ^(.*)anything(.*)$ http://test.com?t=$2 [QSA,L]
```

So when I go to the URL: localhost/mysite/anything/param, I was expecting it to redirect to `http://test.com?t=param`

But it actually goes to `http://test.com`, probably because the `t` variable was blank.

What is the matter with my solution? Do I need to do something else?

Comment: `$2` in your example would evaluate to `/param`, no?

Comment: well, yes. but it stil ignores the parameter